# Grouping similar files in folders

Tags: python, bash, shell, scripting

I would like to group similar files in folders in a same directory. TO give a better idea, i am working on image datasets where I have images of several subjects with varying filenames. however I will have 10-15 images per subject in the dataset too. So lets say subject A will have 10 images named as A_1.png, A_2.png, A_3.png and so on. So, similarly we have n number of subjects. I have to group the subjects in folders having all the images corresponding to that subject. I tried using python but it I was not able to get to the point right. Can we do it using bash or shell scripts? If yes, please advise.

Comment: I saw this exact same question earlier today. What happened with the other one?

Comment: Look for the key word in the file name. If that is there then place in corresponding folder. You'd do this in python by using `if "A" in filename[i]: placeinFolderA`. You can sort through files in bash with `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest this on Shell script, assume I have A_1.png, A_2.png, A_3.png, B_1.png, B_2.png on the working directory. On the first loop I use " _ " as deliminator and on the 2nd loop I use "A/B_" as deliminator:

```
for _DIR in `ls -1 | grep png | awk -F"_" '{print $1}' | uniq`; 
do  
  mkdir $_DIR; 
  for _FILE in `ls -1 | grep $_DIR\_`; 
  do 
    cp $_FILE $_DIR/; 
  done;
  find $_DIR; 
 done;
```

For example:

```
A
A/A_1.png
A/A_2.png
A/A_3.png
B
B/B_1.png
B/B_2.png
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sanwill. I am pretty new to awk. Havent done any tests yet on it. Will keep you posted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. I also put the fake file generator for testing purposes.

Prudential step: 
do rm only after you check everything is ok.

Possible improvement
move/rename files instead of copying and the removing

> for aaa in {1..5} ; do touch SUBJA_${aaa}.txt SUBJB_${aaa}.txt SUBJC_${aaa}.txt; done
>
> for MYSUBJ in SUBJA SUBJB SUBJC
>
> do
>
> mkdir $MYSUBJ
>
> cp $MYSUBJ*.txt $MYSUBJ/
>
> rm $MYSUBJ*.txt
>
> done

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you be more specific? How do I iterate for all the files? I have close to 20000 filenames having 10 clustered filenames per subject. So I have to iterate for 2000 times.

Comment: I think that  sanwill http://stackoverflow.com/users/6828349/sanwill answered to your question nicely!